# Synthethic Phytoplankton

Tags: science-based, biology, science-fiction, environment, fauna

Some people created synthetic bacterial life forms to use them as fuel producers back then; it's called [synthia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycoplasma_laboratorium) I believe... and I don't know how it ended up.

So creating life is already possible. Then say if someone wants to make an upgraded version of phytoplankton with the following changes:

- Reproduces faster than normal plant plankton
- Never truly dies, but cycles life stages like some jellyfish
- Grows faster to produce more oxygen
- Is as resistant as extremophile organisms.

What productive and destructive effects would this über-phytoplankton have on the environment if released inside the oceans?

Comment: You might want to read the story of *Synthia* from the link I added.

Comment: Is it edible? Normal phytoplankton are the base of the marine food chain. If these synthetic ones are edible, your oceans are more productive. If they are inedible or toxic, things that feed on plankton have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phytoplankton are actually non-swimmers and are completely reliant on the current to take them wherever they are going..currents tend to dump large amounts of this plankton in single areas resulting in blooms.  It is true they produce oxygen during photosynthesis, however they can also create some much more toxic things too.

You don't have to look much further than a google search on phytoplankton bloom gulf of mexico.  It's actually considered a natural hazard.

http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/NaturalHazards/view.php?id=14372

> Some blooms, such as red tide, are toxic and result in wide-spread fish deaths. Large blooms can also create dead zones in the ocean—oxygen-poor regions where fish cannot survive—when the plants die. The bacteria that break down the decaying plants consume all of the oxygen, leaving a dead spot. The Gulf of Mexico is annually plagued with one such dead zone every summer near the location of the current bloom.

It's also a yearly occurrence in places like Singapore where it costs the fishing industry several millions a year in losses and they are forced to creative methodologies to get around them.

Comment: does the fact that it doesn't die but cycles life stages continuously  like jellyfishes change the effects it has on the environment?

Comment: I had that same thought when I was posting and starting looking it up...ultimately I would have to assume the plankton would still 'shed' as it transforms from one stage to the next, inviting something (bacteria) to breakdown whatever fell off the plankton as it transitioned from stage to stage.